# Blackout plotted when saved/print as a file

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I am getting blackout in the plot area in the .eps and JPEG  file while save and print function.

here is my code. I tried all these codes but no use.

```
 print -color -depsc test.eps ;
 print ("test.jpg") ;
 print -deps foo.eps;
 print("plot.eps","-deps", "-F:9")
```

Also I am getting  warning: ft_render: unable to set font size to 20.

I have installed Gnu plot and fltk. I could not post the image since I don't have enough reputation.

[Link to the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gygWl.jpg)
 Please help me out.

Regards
Jerome

Comment: Upload the image to another host like imgur and update the post with the url to the pic please. Anyway, your warning doesn't fit with the code you've posted since there's no code about any text being written. Can you update the post with the complete error (if it's longer) and the whole "print-to-file code"?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. Please check the image

Comment: Do you need it in PS format? If not, try:  `saveas(1, "figure.png", png);`

Comment: Please create a minimal example which shows the problem on your system. Use random data or some other artificial data.

Comment: Thanks guys for the inputs but unfortunately it didn't work out.